# Add class to ajax form_for in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am new to ruby on rails. I want add class to a form_for element in rails that using AJAX. Can anybody help me on this?

I tried some myself by googling, but its not working.

My code is.

```
<%= form_for(@user, remote: doajax), :html => {:class => 'newuserform'} do |f| %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't put the parens around here: `form_for(@user, remote: doajax)`. You're closing off those arguments to `form_for` and the `html =>` argument is not being passed to `form_for`.

Make it:

```
<%= form_for @user, remote: doajax, :html => {:class => 'newuserform'} do |f| %>
```

Better yet, use the new hash syntax:

```
<%= form_for @user, remote: doajax, html: { class: 'newuserform' } do |f| %>
```